# Add missing dates when using GROUP BY in SQLITE

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have a following table that contains each sale and records time of sale in UNIX Epoch.

Sale:

```
id | product_id | salesperson_id | time
--------------------------------------------
1  | 1          | 3              | 1638263007
2  | 1          | 2              | 1638262007
3  | 2          | 2              | 1638261007
```

I would like to generate a report of daily sales as seen below:

```
Days  | Sales
-------------
27/12 | 10
26/12 | 2
**-- missing 25/12 --**
24/12 | 2
```

Obviously 25/21 is missing because there were no sales that day. However, I would like it to show 0 sales for such days. I'm generating dates in order to join them but I'm still facing the same issue where certain dates are missing due to no sales that day.

```
WITH RECURSIVE Dates(date) AS (
  VALUES(date('now', '-7 day'))
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day')
  FROM Dates
  WHERE date < date('now')
)

SELECT strftime('%d/%m', Dates.date) AS Days, COALESCE(COUNT(*), 0) AS Sales
FROM Sale
LEFT JOIN Dates ON strftime('%d/%m', DATETIME(Sale.time, 'unixepoch')) = Days
WHERE Sale.time >= strftime('%s', 'now', '-7 day')
GROUP BY Days
ORDER BY Sale.time DESC
```

Is there anything I could do different to get the following output?

```
Days  | Sales
-------------
27/12 | 10
26/12 | 2
25/12 | 0
24/12 | 2
```

Comment: This would be easy to handle in Python, rather than trying to come up with an SQL hack.

Comment: @TimRoberts recursive ctes are not a hack. They are common practice and in this case the simplest way to deal with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a `LEFT` join of the CTE to the table:

```
WITH Dates(date) AS (
  SELECT date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT date(date, '+1 day') 
  FROM Dates
  WHERE date < CURRENT_DATE
)
SELECT strftime('%d/%m', d.date) AS Days, 
       COUNT(s.id) AS Sales
FROM Dates d LEFT JOIN Sale s 
ON date(s.time, 'unixepoch') = d.date
GROUP BY d.date
ORDER BY d.date DESC;
```

Note that if you want results for the last 7 days including the current day you should use `date(CURRENT_DATE, '-6 day')` instead of `date(CURRENT_DATE, '-7 day')` as the starting date.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e8d9d6c1568f3ecf12081466f663fa1d).

Comment: Amazing! Works great for daily reports. Can this be modified to generate monthly or even yearly reports?

Comment: It seem the query does not add a months worth of sales correctly when the following parameters are changed:  `SELECT date(CURRENT_DATE, '-4 month')`, `SELECT date(date, '+1 month')`

Comment: @acer you can modify the starting and ending dates to get any report that you want. You just have to pick the correct dates. If you want to change the grouping from days to months or years you must also change the ON clause.